# Sqlserver: what are the differences between execute sql with jdbc driver and execute with sql client

Tags: java, sql-server, jdbc, collation

I have a table named "T_ROLE", it has just one column named "NAME" which type is nvarchar(255), the sqlserver Collation is "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS"(en_US), now i want to insert japanese character, so i know that i need do sql like this:

```
INSERT INTO T_ROLE(NAME) VALUES(N'japaneseString')
```

this can be successful.

if i do sql:

```
INSERT INTO T_ROLE(NAME) VALUES('japaneseString')
```

which without N prefix, it will saved as '?', i can under these behavior.

But when i use sqlserver jdbc driver to do insert operation like this:

```
String sql = "INSERT INTO T_ROLE (NAME) VALUES(?)";
stmt.setString(1, "");
stmt.execute(sql);
```

notice: i don't use stmt.setNString() method, but it can be saved successful, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this blog: https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlcat/2010/04/05/character-data-type-conversion-when-using-sql-server-jdbc-drivers/

> It turns out that the **JDBC driver sends character data including varchar() as nvarchar() by default**. The reason is to minimize client side conversion from Java’s native string type, which is Unicode.
>
> So how do you force the JDBC driver not to behave this way? There is a connection string property, named `sendStringParametersAsUnicode`. By default it’s true.
>
> One would ask what if I want to pass both varchar and nvarchar parameters at the same time? Well, even with the connection property set false, you can explicitly specify nvarchar type like this:
>
> ```
> pStmt.setObject(2,Id,Types.NVARCHAR); //Java app code
> ```

Simple [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q=sql+server+jdbc+nvarchar) for `sql server jdbc nvarchar` found this answer.